# Corzetti / tough and chewy?

Tags: pasta

I gave **corzetti** (see [Corzetti pasta](https://romagnolipastatools.com/corzetti/)) a try a few weeks ago.  Made the dough by hand and rolled it out with a pasta roller.  Used a #3 thickness (see [Kitchen Aid pasta roller](https://www.kitchenaid.com/countertop-appliances/stand-mixers/attachments/p.3-piece-pasta-roller-and-cutter-set.ksmpra.html)) which is quite a bit thicker than a fettuccine.  The recipe I used was essentially flour / water / egg.  Some corzetti recipes call for crushed walnuts; I have yet to try that.

Let the corzetti dry for no more than 45 min before cooking.  Boiled the corzetti in salted water and served with sauce.

- The corzetti were *toothy*; very chewy to the point of being *too chewy*

Is this:

1. Traditional?  The way they should taste?  Should they be any different than an *al dente* pasta?
2. Is it an indication of

- the ingredients?
- drying time?
- cooking time?
- thickness of the pasta before pressing?

I enjoy cooking pasta in sauce rather than just dressing the pasta in sauce.  *Will this make them tougher?*

Comment: How long did you boil them?  How did you check for doneness?

Comment: First tried to boil them until they floated.  It was easy to tell that they were al dente.  Then let them cook ten more minutes and they were softer.  With most homemade pastas if they are overcooked, they melt.  Is this not the case with a thicker pasta like corzetti?  I'd estimate the total cooking time to be 15 minutes.  There were many batches; they were cooked in stages - about (x2) bowls of pasta each - and all turned out about the same.  I've never cooked a homemade pasta for as long as I cooked these... most melt long before 15 min!

Comment: Wow, 10 minutes is a long time.  Most recipes recommend 4.  Is it possible they got chewier because of the extra cooking?  Also, what kind of flour are you using?

Comment: I agree... 10 min is a very long time.  Standard bleached white flour.  This basic pasta recipe has worked fine for fettuccine and similar.  Again, the differences being that fettuccine is at a roller setting of #5 to #6 (much thinner).  The experience with fettuccine at this thickness is that 10 min would melt it into goo in a pot of boiling water.

Comment: Hmmm.  I really can't imagine why it would be that chewy then.  I've made white flour dumplings that are 1/2" thick, and tender.  Hopefully an Italian who's made these before will speak up.

Comment: I'm also at a loss... I too am looking for somebody that has had them in Italy (Genovese?)